# How can define a set of nested parameters

Tags: functions, evaluation, function-construction, functional-style

I would like to know how I to define a function with a nested set of parameters (or whatever you would like to call it). For example, how would I get the following function `A`,

```
M = m1 + m2;
\[Eta] = m1*m2/(m1 + m2)^2
A[t_]:= M (\[Eta] / M * t)^(1/4);
```

Such that if I just evaluated `A[5.0]` for example it would return,

```
1.49535 M Power[\[Eta]/M, (4)^-1]
```

(i.e. a function of `M` and `\[Eta]`) or something similar, but not `A` as a function of `m1`, `m2`,

```
1.49535 Power[(m1 m2)/(m1+m2)^2, (4)^-1] (m1+m2)
```

But, at the same time, maintain a form that I could replace either `m1` and `m2` or `M` and `\[Eta]`, such that both

```
A[5.0] /. m1 -> 1 /. m2 -> 1
A[5.0] /. M -> 2 /. \[Eta] -> 1/4
```

would return `1.77828`.

Comment: Don't use capital letters for the starting char of your vars/functions. You'll collide with Mma internal symbols

Answer (score 2):

You could define (heeding @belisarius comment) :

```
bigM[m1_, m2_] = m1 + m2;
\[Eta][m1_, m2_] = m1*m2/(m1 + m2)^2
bigA[m_, eta_, t_] := m (eta/m*t)^(1/4);
```

Then :

```
bigA[m, eta, 5.0]
(* 1.49535 (eta/m)^(1/4) m *)

bigA[bigM[1, 1], \[Eta][1, 1], 5.0]
(* 1.77828 *)
```

Comment: Thanks @b.gatessucks, I guess that would work. But in the latter example, I would have to input the `m1`, `m2` data twice.

Answer (score 2):

As belisarius comments it is best to avoid using Symbol names that are or start with capital letters to avoid collisions with existing or future system functions.  Nevertheless I will preserve your usage for clarity.

Taking the question at face value you might use something like this:

```
def[_, value_?NumericQ] := value
MakeBoxes[def[name_, value_], _] := name

M = def["M", m1 + m2];
\[Eta] = def["\[Eta]", m1*m2/(m1 + m2)^2];
A[t_] := M (\[Eta]/M*t)^(1/4);

A[5.0]
```

> ```
> 1.49535 M (\[Eta]/M)^(1/4)
> ```

```
A[5.0] /. m1 -> 1 /. m2 -> 1
A[5.0] /. M -> 2 /. \[Eta] -> 1/4
```

> ```
> 1.77828
>
> 1.77828
> ```

If this does not work in practice you will need to provide some additional context for your question.