# How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation, faq

I am trying to get my head around how `Manipulate` evaluates functions in a Plot. I have read the introduction to Manipulate, and introduction to Dynamic, but I still can't figure it.

For my specific example, I have a function `bigA` parameterised by `m1` and `m2` (this relates to [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10600)),

```
bigA[t_]:= (m1+m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1+m2)^3)^0.25
```

So when I try to plot it in Manipulate,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[bigA[t], {t, 1, 10}],
 {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
 {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

Nothing appears. I presume this is because `m1` and `m2` aren't being evaluated. But I don't know what the order is supposed to be.

## Edit

The thing is, this seems to work when I `Evaluate` and don't plot, i.e,

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@bigA[t],
 {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
 {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

So couldn't I just stick a `Plot` command in there somewhere?

Comment: I think, [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808) is strongly relevant, even though not being specifically about `Manipulate`, since your real question is on how to properly localize variables in functions definitions - as the answers posted already also indicate.

Comment: Related: [(8625)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8625/121)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `Manipulate`, `m1` and `m2` are replaced with localized versions (as in `Module`) rather than assigned (as in `Block`). Since the `m1` and `m2` from `bigA` are outside the `Manipulate`, and `bigA[t]` is evaluated only after the replacement of `m1` and `m2` inside the `Manipulate`, they are not affected by the manipulation.

The best solution is to give `m1` and `m2` as extra arguments:

```
bigA[t_, m1_, m2_] := (m1+m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1+m2)^3)^0.25
Manipulate[Plot[bigA[t, m1, m2], {t, 1, 10}],
           {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
           {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

If for some reason you cannot do that, you can also use replacement rules as follows:

```
bigA[t_] := (m1+m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1+m2)^3)^0.25
Manipulate[Plot[bigA[t]/.{m1->mm1,m2->mm2}, {t, 1, 10}],
           {{mm1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
           {{mm2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

This works because `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) does the replacements only after the left hand side has been evaluated, and the `mm1` and `mm2` are now inside the `Manipulate`, so they can be properly localized.

About your edit:

By adding `Evaluate@` at the beginning of the argument to `Manipulate`, you override Mathematica's order of evaluation. So with

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@bigA[t],
           {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
           {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

Mathematica *first* evaluates `bigA[t]` to `(m1+m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1+m2)^3)^0.25`, and only *then* proceeds to evaluate the `Manipulate`, which therefore sees the `m1` and `m2`.

Now this will *not* work with `Plot`, because the whole `Plot` statement will be executed, before `Manipulate` will have a chance to insert `m1` and `m2`. So when `Plot` evaluates `bigA[t]`, it will receive an expression containing `m1` and `m2` instead of a number, and thus produce an empty graph. *This graph* (which no longer contains any trace of `m1` or `m2`) will then be passed to `Manipulate`. Of course replacing `m1` and `m2` at this stage doesn't work, because they already vanished.

So in essence, while without `Evaluate`, `m1` and `m2` are substituted too late, with `Evaluate@Plot` they are consumed too early.

Now you might have the idea to use `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@bigA[t],...],...]` instead, in order to evaluate `bigA[t]` (to get `m1` and `m2` visible) but not `Plot` (because that only works after `m1` and `m2` got a value). However that doesn't work either, because `Evaluate` only affects order of evaluation when it appears as immediate argument of the expression being evaluated. So while evaluating `Manipulate`, the `Evaluate` in the argument of `Plot` is not considered. It will be considered at the time `Plot` is evaluated, but at that time it's already too late.

Comment: Thanks @celtschk, what about the case where I evaluate the function, but don't plot it (please see my edited question above). Why would this work, but not the plot?

Comment: @ShaunH: That works because you added an explicit `Evaluate` here, overriding the standard order of evaluation. Note however that this works only if the `Evaluate` is top-level on the `Manipulate` argument.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation on how Evaluate works. That really did confuse me. So basically, it only works at the top level. Ok, so I will just have to define the parameters as variables.

Comment: Shouldn't the first Manipulate not have `bigA[t,m1,m2]` instead of `bigA[t]`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, you're right. I'll correct this.

Comment: the second method works perfect when combining manipulate and the contourplot3d command. One needs to add Evaluate inside the Contourplot3d command, and the substitution right after the contourplot3d function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The replacement rule in the second solution should be inside `Plot[]`: `Plot[bigA[t] /. {m1 -> mm1, m2 -> mm2}, {t, 1, 10}]`.  Since you haven't been around in a month or so, I'll edit.  You can fix it how you like, if you don't like what I did.

Answer (score 14):

A couple of tips:

- Make sure you evaluate the function - best way is to put it in `Initialization :> ...`
- Rather keep parameters m1, m2 as arguments
- Fix `PlotRange` to see function change, not the axes scale
- Use `SaveDefinitions -> True` so interface will remember your defined function when you reopen notebook

I updated the code below to encompass your derivative question:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@{bigA[t, m1, m2], D[bigA[t, m1, m2], t]}, {t, 1, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 3}, Filling -> 0], {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}, {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}, 
 Initialization :> (bigA[t_, m1_, m2_] := (m1 + m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1 + m2)^3)^0.25), 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vitaliy. So the key change here is to put the parameters `m1` and `m2` as functions, right? I guess that is just the way you should do things in Mathematica. But for some reason it doesn't seem right to me. For example, if I wanted to differentiate bigA with respect to t, would `m1` and `m2` still be kept symbolic?

Comment: @ShaunH (1) you mean m1 and m2 as "variables", - and the answer is yes, celtschk in his answer has good explanation. (2) yes, m1 and m2 would still be kept symbolic, in Mathematica by default almost everything is symbolic, unless defined to be numeric. I updated the code to illustrate this by adding the computation and graph of derivative

Comment: Sorry, I meant variables, not functions. You've almost sold me that this should be the way to go, except for one thing. It seems to work when you Evaluate, but not plot (see my edit to the original question). Isn't there someway we could just include an Evaluate command and keep `m1`, `m2` as parameters?

Answer (score 11):

`Manipulate` does not temporarily change the global value of its variables, as does `Table` and `Do`.  Compare:

```
Dynamic[x]
Do[Pause[1], {x, 0, 10}]
```

With:

```
Dynamic[x]
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Since your definition of `bigA` relies on `` Global` `` symbols `m1` and `m2` you must manually change these values, e.g. using `Block`:

```
bigA[t_] := (m1 + m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1 + m2)^3)^0.25

Manipulate[
 Block[{m1 = mm1, m2 = mm2},
  Plot[bigA[t], {t, 1, 10}]
 ],
 {{mm1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
 {{mm2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}
]
```

Or you could insert the definition of `bigA` into manipulate using `With` so that it appears explicitly (assuming no global values for `m1`, `m2`, or `t`):

```
With[{x = bigA[t]},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[x, {t, 1, 10}],
  {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
  {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}
 ]
]
```

Simpler and cleaner is to just parametrize `m1` and `m2` as belisarius shows.

Answer (score 9):

For example you can do the following to get proper localization

```
bigA[t_, m1_, m2_] := (m1 + m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1 + m2)^3)^0.25
Manipulate[
 Plot[bigA[t, m1, m2], {t, 1, 10}],
 {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
 {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

Answer (score 5):

This works and is very simple!!

```
bigA[t_] := (m1 + m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1 + m2)^3)^0.25;
Manipulate[
  Plot[#, {t, 1, 10}], 
  {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
  {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}] &@bigA[t]
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy-paste the definition of the function (or evaluate it and copy the resulting code) to inside the plot. In other words

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(m1+m2) ((m1 m2 t)/(m1+m2)^3)^0.25, {t, 1, 10}],
 {{m1, 1.4}, 0.8, 3},
 {{m2, 1.4}, 0.8, 3}]
```

I understand that this is not the neatest solution, but the big elephant in the room is that this is by far the simplest and most convenient way to circumvent this limitation.