# How can I write a Do loop that iterates over N iterators when N is not known a-priori?

Tags: programming, iterators

For any positive integer $n$ which is not specified *a priori*, I can make $n$-tuple vector $v$ by `v = Array[a, 1, n]`. Now, given that $n$ is a positive integer which is not specified *a priori*, I want to write an iteration sentence which performs over $1\leq a_1,\ldots, a_n\leq 3$. ($a_i$ are integers and hence I will get $3^n$ iterations).

For example, if $n=2$, my sentence plays the same role as the following loop:

```
Do[EXPERIMENT, {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

If $n=3$, my sentence plays the same role as the following:

```
Do[EXPERIMENT, {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}].
```

I can do it for any given SPECIFIED integer $n$, but I want to write the universal looping sentence which iterates for $1\leq a_1,\ldots, a_n\leq 3$ ($a_i$ are integers.)

Comment: Something like this? `f[n_] := Module[{i = 1},
  Do[Print@i++, 
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Thread[List[Array[a, n], 1, 3]]]]]; f[4]`

Comment: Also, the tagging looks inappropriate. Anyone?

Comment: That's what I want!

Answer (score 3):

Following belisarius' suggestion you might use something like:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]

f[body_, n_Integer?Positive, m__:3] := Block[{a},
  Do[body, ##] & @@ Thread[{Array[a, n], m}]
]
```

Use:

```
f[Print[a[1], a[2], a[3]], 3]

f[Print[a[1], a[2]], 2, 4]

f[Print[a[1], a[2]], 2, 5, 7]
```

[How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/121)

The second parameter is your `n` value.  The third and following parameters are the range specification for the loops.

I Blocked `a` to prevent a global assignment to that symbol from breaking the function.

Comment: Faster than me ;) +1

Comment: @Rojo Well it only took me 6+ hours... :^)  And I thought you were in bed?

Comment: Haha, I just came back home, was about to go to bed, saw the other question, commented, and when I was about to lie down, it was stronger than me to come and answer. Then I saw this one, started to type `Do[` and your answer appeared

Comment: @rojo I'd love that sort of auto-completion - start typing, and Mr Wizard fills the rest in for me...!

Answer (score 1):

Say for $n=1$, you have defined `f[{i1}]` as your first experiment. For $n=2$, your experiments are defined by `f[{i1,i2}]`, for $n=3$ the experiments are defined by `f[{i1,i2,i3}]` and etc, with the idea that you wish to allow $n$ such experiments. If you structure your experiments this way, then you can create a list of all experiments by

```
m = 3; n = 3; c = Tuples[Range[m], n]
```

Here $m$ is the number of values each variable is to take on, and $n$ is how many variables you have. Now you can run all your experiments at once using

```
Map[f, c]
```

or use the shortcut

```
f /@ c
```

For $m=n=3$, this gives

```
{f[{1, 1, 1}], f[{1, 1, 2}], f[{1, 1, 3}], f[{1, 2, 1}], f[{1, 2, 2}],
 f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{1, 3, 1}], f[{1, 3, 2}], f[{1, 3, 3}], 
 f[{2, 1, 1}], f[{2, 1, 2}], f[{2, 1, 3}], f[{2, 2, 1}], f[{2, 2, 2}],
 f[{2, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 1}], f[{2, 3, 2}], f[{2, 3, 3}], 
 f[{3, 1, 1}], f[{3, 1, 2}], f[{3, 1, 3}], f[{3, 2, 1}], f[{3, 2, 2}],
 f[{3, 2, 3}], f[{3, 3, 1}], f[{3, 3, 2}], f[{3, 3, 3}]}
```

so you can see all 3^3 experiments will run. In general you will have $n^m$ experiments. As Mr. Wizard suggests, an alternative to `Map` would be to use `Scan`:

```
Scan[Print[f[#]] &, c]
```

This might be preferred if your experiment function `f` has "side effects", such as making assignments, or generating output, since `Scan` will suppress these.

Comment: I thought about posting something like this but held off because I thought `Do` might be specified because of memory restrictions.  Nevertheless the packed array from `Tuples` is compact, and this should be practical for a large range of applications.  I would however mention `Scan` as that is more analogous to `Do`.  +1

Comment: Mr. Wizard -- Yes, I agree I was taking some liberties with the question: but this is one of the things with functional programming - if you plan ahead and build your "experiments" correctly, then later steps (like this one) become almost trivial. In fact, I would say planning ahead is important in *any* kind of programming.