# Abridging Lists of Equations within NDSolve, Manipulate

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, manipulate, replacement

I have a pretty little `NDSolve` function that I've finally decked out with manipulatable (by sliders) coefficients, which changes the graph in real time.  However, I used dummy equations in making sure I could set up the system I want, which I have as you can see by simply copy-pasting:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[{a[t], b[t], c[t]} /.
    NDSolve[
     {a'[t] == -k1f*a[t] + k1r*b[t],
      b'[t] == k1f*a[t] - k1r*b[t] - k2f*b[t],
      c'[t] == k2f*b[t],
      a[0] == a0,
      b[0] == 0.0,
      c[0] == 0.0},
     {a, b, c}, {t, 0, 1500}, MaxSteps -> 1000, AccuracyGoal -> 10]],
  {t, 0, 1500}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1500}, {0, 0.11}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time (Seconds)", "Concentration"},
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.008]}, {Green, 
     Thickness[0.008]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.008]}}],
 {{k1f, 0.01, Subscript[k, 1]}, 0, 0.02},
 {{k1r, 0.01, Subscript[k, -1]}, 0, 0.02},
 {{k2f, 0.01, Subscript[k, 2]}, 0, 0.02},
 {{a0, 0.1, Subscript[a, init]}, 0, .2}]
```

All I want is to rename my equations `(a'[t], b'[t], c'[t])` in the first argument of `NDSolve` to a nickname, eqns, to simplify looking at them when they aren't the dummy 3 equations but are my real 150 equations, instead.

But `eqns = {a'[t] == -k1f*a[t] + k1r*b[t], ...` as is done in the first argument of `NDSolve` above, followed by `NDSolve[z,{a, b, c}, etc.] returns a ridiculous number of errors.

Where am I going wrong?

***Answered!***  For those of you still confused after reading the original question's answer (linked above), please see the comments for a short answer as to how to address my scenario specifically.

Comment: You need to name your equations `eqs[k1f, k1r, a0, k2f]` so that you are affecting the variables within the equations themselves when you use `Manipulate`: `eqs[k1f_, k1r_, a0_, k2f_] = {a'[t] == -k1f*a[t] + k1r*b[t], b'[t] == k1f*a[t] - k1r*b[t] - k2f*b[t], c'[t] == k2f*b[t], a[0] == a0, b[0] == 0.0, c[0] == 0.0};`

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/121

Comment: @Shock Thank you both, apologies for the duplicate entry.  If I do find a solution based on the article and this one isn't closed, I'll update my progress.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ^ (See Above) Wouldn't let me post two notifications simultaneously.

Comment: My confusion in relating his question to mine is in defining (what he called `bigA[t_]`) and what I suppose I would call `eqns[a'_, b'_, c'_, a_. b_, c_]`... I will sit on this and update as I progress.

Comment: Ah, @Stock I see exactly what you mean now, which clears up my previous comment above.  I'm glad I re-read your comment after looking at Mr. Wizard's link.  It is `eqns` as a function of those parameters being changed with manipulate that I want to place within `NDSolve`, not `eqns` as a function of the dependent variables within `NDSolve`.  Thank you both.  I see the relevance of what you linked as well, Mr. Wizard.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What is the best way to go about marking a question as answered if the answer can be found in one or more comments?  Thanks again, fellows.

Comment: If the question is answered in another question it should be closed as "already answered here..." (duplicate).  If it is answered in comments that are not a duplicate of an earlier answer then an answer should be posted.  You can either encourage someone (@Jonathan) to post an answer, or you can post it yourself and Accept your own answer.  Either is appreciated and better than having a question appear unresolved when it is really not.  In this case three people feel this is a duplicate and I tend to agree with them, unless you have strong feeling to the contrary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree that it is a duplicate.  My initial confusion was, I think, more due to my own novice than any lack of similarity between this question and the link you posted.  Thank you both.