# Autonomous equations' critical points and eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations

I have three-dimensional autonomous equations and want to find their critical points and corresponding eigenvalues. They have 6 critical points each.

`x`, `y` and `z` are functions of time and `m` is a function of `z/y`

```
x'=-1 - z - 3*y + x^2 - x*z,
y'=(x*z/m[z/y]) - y*(2*z - 4 - x),
z'=-(x*z/m[z/y]) - 2 z*(z - 2),
```

I wrote this code but it didn't work. Top of the page says running but nothing happens.

```
f[x, y, z] == -1 - z - 3*y + x^2 - x*z
g[x, y, z] == (x*z/m[z/y]) - y*(2*z - 4 - x)
h[x, y, z] == -(x*z/m[z/y]) - 2 z*(z - 2)

sys == {D[x[t], t] == f[x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
  D[y[t], t] == g[x[t], y[t], z[t]], 
  D[z[t], t] == h[x[t], y[t], z[t]]};

Solve[{f[x, y, z] == 0, g[x, y, z] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: First, use `:=` and patterns to [define functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).  Second, without the function `m`, I doubt someone will understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 5):

For me, `Solve` reports an error until only the right side is extracted (without the derivative) via

```
eqns =
 {x' == -1 - z - 3*y + x^2 - x*z,
  y' == (x*z/m[z/y]) - y*(2*z - 4 - x),
  z' == -(x*z/m[z/y]) - 2 z*(z - 2)}
```

and isolating RHS to avoid a "This cannot be solved via the methods available to`Solve`" error,

```
listRHS = eqns /. (lhs_ == rhs_) :> (rhs)    

Solve[Thread[listRHS == 0], {x, y, z}]
```

which together make the seperate definition of f[x,y,z], etc. unnecessary for a moment (which may end up actually being more convenient for you given that `Solve` runs *seemingly* indefinitely).

The reason for this is because some systems never reach true equilibrium (asymptotically for example).  You can still get numerical solutions within `NDSolve` and [track equilibrium](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/480/how-to-use-ndsolve-to-track-equilibrium), incorporating a threshold in the form of a `Method` within the numerical integrator that then `Reaps` the just how small the derivatives of your state variables are at that time.

For example if

```
dstateVariables = {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}
```

then your addition to Sjoerd's answer here (while they are all excellent, his lack of 3rd party functions supports things like `PrecisionalGoal`, `AccuracyGoal` etc.) would be:

```
equilibriaThreshold = 
 10^-11.1;  (* Units of state variable input per unit time. *)
equiCond = Total@Thread[Abs@dstateVariablesExplicit];

Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> equiCond < equilibriaThreshold, 
"EventAction" :> Throw[end = t, "StopIntegration"]}
```

Where as you can see, the equilibrium condition achieved in my system (which is the sum of 100+ state variables' derivatives) is ***damned small*** , so pretty much zero (steady-state).  The `Throw` term in the last line tells it to automatically stop the integration automatically once the relative equilibria time is found.

This works with 100+ coupled differential equations within a `Manipulate` that isn't too slow.  Similarly, I tried using `Solve` with the steady-state scenario; a few nine to twelve hour waits while Mathematica populates all 8 GB of RAM were my punishment then.

If you want to begin to format your equations for input into NDSolve, the answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25865/format-preservation-of-fullsimplify-on-indexed-system-of-autonomous-equations) may be of interest.  In fact, while [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25699/abridging-lists-of-equations-within-ndsolve-manipulate) was a novice question (& duplicate), in ***the question***, when posting it, I provided the code (mostly found elsewhere) to construct the `Manipulate` to vary any physical constants etc. via real-time sliders, which more than encompasses the proper formatting necessary for input into `NDSolve` etc.  Then, all you've left to do is step through the motions of other answers (such as Sjoerd's linked earlier) to come up with the equilibria.

I just started about four months ago, so it's certainly within your capacity to set this up.  If I think of further details I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it in another way and got an answer, but under the assumption that  `m = constant` :

```
Clear[x, y, z];
crit = Solve[
  {-1 - z - 3 y + x^2 - x*z == 0, 
   (x*z)/m + 4 y - 2 y*z + x*y == 0,
   -(x*z)/m - 2 z^2 + 4 z == 0},
  {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -4, y -> 5, z -> 0}, {x -> -1, y -> 0, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> 0, y -> -1, z -> 2}, {x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 0}, 
>   {x -> (3 m)/(1 + m), y -> 1/6 (-6 + (9 m)/(1 + m)^2 + 
>       (18 m^2)/(1 + m)^2 + 3/(1 + m) - (12 m)/(1 + m)), 
>    z -> (1 + 4 m)/(2 (1 + m))}, 
>   {x -> -((2 (-1 + m))/(1 + 2 m)), 
>    y -> -((6 m - (4 (-1 + m)^2)/(1 + 2 m)^2 - (8 (-1 + m)^2 m)/(1 + 2 m)^2 +
>       (2 (-1 + m))/(1 + 2 m) - (8 (-1 + m) m)/(1 + 2 m))/(6 m)), 
>    z -> (-1 + 3 m + 4 m^2)/(m (1 + 2 m))}}
> ```

but if take m(z/y) after some time *Mathematica* returns:

> ```
> No more memory available.
> Mathematica kernel has shut down.
> Try quitting other applications and then retry.
> ```

What do you think guys ?

Comment: First I think that it's `Clear` and not `clear`.

Comment: Without knowing anything about `m[...]` I think you have a functional equation and not an algebraic system.