# Manipulate - Plot - Function with Parameters

Tags: plotting, manipulate

dear community!

How do I make this construction work?

```
f[x_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate [f[x_]], {x, 0, 5},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotRange -> All
  ],
 {{b, 0.1}, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled" }
 ]
```

Thank you very much for detailed reply and suggested reading.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
f[x_, b_] := x^2 + b
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, b], {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
          {{b, 0.1}, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I know this question is a duplicate; in fact I think you answered the earlier one.  Would you help me find it?

Comment: I found it: [(10605)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10605/121). Next time please search before answering.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard O my! That was two years ago! [Forgetting is a virtue too, do you know that?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funes_the_Memorious)

Comment: I forget a great deal, nevertheless I do my best to keep the site organized.  The original question came up rather quickly searching for Manipulate and Plot; you could likely have found it faster than writing this answer.  I am just asking for help with the process.  If you search and find nothing by all means post an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sometimes I just want to relax and answer simple questions. Almost always _trying_ to do my best. Anyway, please try to forgive misbehaving children like me.

Comment: lol -- Okay, point taken.  Thanks for having a sense of humor about it.  Sorry if I was rude.  I feel a bit overwhelmed these days chasing duplicates.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Don't worry, you're doing a great job. As an aside, I'm not always in the mood to spend more time searching a dup than what takes me writing a one-liner. Nevertheless I understand that keeping the site clean _is_ crucial, so I try to balance as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time and answering the question. Excuse me please for posting a duplicate. Next time I will be searching more thoroughly.