# Is this a bug? Trivial semantic difference => different behavior

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This is a problem of no special significance or difficulty. I trimmed it down to the minimum to demonstrate the frustrating behavior:

```
(DSolve[{ y''[t] + +y'[t] + v y[t] == Sin[w t], y[0] == 0, 
 y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t][[1, 1, 2]]) // FullSimplify
```

assume the above is the first action in a new kernel session

```
Manipulate[Plot[%1, {t, .01, 10}], {v, 2, 5}, {w, 6, 10}]
```

This gives something that works

repeat the *exact* above except name the solution, and then try to use that in the second expression:

```
vvv = (DSolve[{ y''[t] + +y'[t] + v y[t] == Sin[w t], y[0] == 0, 
 y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t][[1, 1, 2]]) // FullSimplify

Manipulate[Plot[vvv, {t, .01, 10}], {v, 2, 5}, {w, 6, 10}]
```

This last form gives a dumb, mute manipulate. Sliders move, but you get nothing - no output.

This is Mathematica 10.1.0 on OSX 10.11.6

If this is a bug, I'm speechless. If there's something I'm missing then I'd love to know what it is).

Comment: The second example works correctly because `Manipulate` is a scoping construct. I'm not sure why the first one works but I know this question was already asked here. It is just hard to search for %

Comment: [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478)

Comment: @kuba do you mean "the second one works _incorrectly_ ?

Comment: No, this time I made no typo :P Manipulate scopes `v` and `w` before it sees `v` and `w` from `vvv` so at the end we have two sets of symbols. Have you read the link from my second topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explicit arguments in `vvv`

```
vvv[t_, v_, w_] = 
  DSolve[{y''[t] + +y'[t] + v y[t] == Sin[w t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], 
     t][[1, 1, 2]] // FullSimplify;

Manipulate[
 Plot[vvv[t, v, w], {t, .01, 10}],
 {v, 2, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {w, 6, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This "just makes it work" - does not explain why the second case (giving the solution a name, in this case vvv) makes the Manipulate mute/nonfunctional.

Comment: @Paul_A - @Kuba already told you that it is a scoping issue. `Manipulate` has the the attribute `HoldAll` which keeps the variables in `vvv` from being associated with the control variables unless the association is made by the use of explicit arguments in `vvv[t, v, w]`. Alternatively, you could move the definition of `vvv` inside the `Manipulate`.