# How to add element to a list once and then the last element will get replaced in the following iterations?

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation, broken-code

```
img= ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}];    
Manipulate[
colors = {Black, Blue, Purple, Red, Brown, Gray, Green, Orange, Pink,
Cyan, Yellow, White};
w = List @@@ ColorConvert[colors, "RGB"].{0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140};
opacities = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12};
co = Table[AppendTo[colors[[i]], opacities[[i]]], {i, 12}];
colorfn = Evaluate[Blend[{w, co}\[Transpose], #]] &;
Image3D[img, 
ColorFunction -> colorfn], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, {x4, 
0, 1}, {x5, 0, 1}, {x6, 0, 1}, {x7, 0, 1}, {x8, 0, 1}, {x9, 0, 
1}, {x10, 0, 1}, {x11, 0, 1}, {x12, 0, 1}]
```

The above code snippet works fine. However, 'AppendTo' adds an element on each iteration. I want to append the opacity values to be appended to the color values only once (during the execution of the Manipulate for the first time) and from the next time onwards (for any change in the parameters x1, x2, ..) it will just replace the last the opacity value.

[

```
Table[AppendTo[colors[[i]], opacities[[i]]], {i, 12}]
```

results

```
{GrayLevel[0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0], RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5, 0], 
RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0], GrayLevel[0.5, 0],  
RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5, 0], 
RGBColor[0, 1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], GrayLevel[1, 0]}
(*when it is first called*)
```

Next iteration ...

```
{GrayLevel[0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0], 
RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0], GrayLevel[0.5, 0, 0],  
RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0], 
RGBColor[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], GrayLevel[1, 0, 0]}
```

and so on.
]

How can I modify the above code to serve the purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is the use of `AppendTo` where `Append` would suffice.  You could instead use:

```
co = MapThread[Append, {colors, opacities}];
```

Full code:

*Okay, cleaner now*

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}];

colors =
 {Black, Blue, Purple, Red, Brown, Gray, Green, Orange, Pink, Cyan, Yellow, White};

vars = Array[α, Length@colors];

w = List @@@ ColorConvert[colors, "RGB"].{0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140};

makeColorFn[colors_, w_, vars_] :=
 {w, MapThread[Append, {colors, vars}]}\[Transpose] /. body_ :> (Blend[body, #] &)

With[{opa = vars},
  Manipulate[
    Image3D[img, ColorFunction -> makeColorFn[colors, w, opa]],
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 1} & /@ vars)]
  ]
]
```

[image]

In the code above `With` is used to address

- [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/121)

---

An alternative to the way I used `makeColorFn` above is this:

```
myBlend[body_][n_] := Blend[body, n]

colorfn = myBlend[{w, MapThread[Append, {colors, vars}]}\[Transpose]];

With[{colorfn = colorfn}, 
  Manipulate[
    Image3D[img, ColorFunction -> colorfn], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, 1} & /@ vars)]
  ]
]
```

The key here is to inject a color function in a form that is open to evaluation so that it "picks up" the values of `α[x]`.  `Function` doesn't work here as its body is held.  Compare:

```
Manipulate[Blend[x, #] &, {x, 0, 5}]

Manipulate[myBlend[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

I still need `With` to get `colorfn` inside `Manipulate` *before* it is evaluated and the GUI is built, or the `vars` variables are not recognized and replaced correctly.

Comment: Excellent. That's the power of Mathematica. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Majis You're welcome.  I made one more code adjustment hoping to better show what needs to be inside `Manipulate` and what does not.

Comment: @Majis I thought of another example that I felt I should share.  `Manipulate` and friends are rather tricky and it's important to see multiple examples that work as well as some that don't, IMHO.  I hope this one is helpful to you.