# Rebuild a vector defining the sign of the elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I try to better define my question.

I have a vector q:

```
q={(2 (3 d^4 + 8 d^3 h - 30 d^2 h^2 + 20 d h^3))/((3 d - 4 h)^2 (d - 2 
h)^2), ( 2 d - 3 h)/(d - 2 h), (-3 d^3 + 5 d^2 h - 2 d h^2)/((3 d - 4 h) (d 
- 2 h)^2), ( 2 d - 3 h)/(d - 2 h), (-3 d^3 + 5 d^2 h - 2 d h^2)/((3 d - 4 h) 
(d - 2 h)^2), 1 + d/(2 (d - 2 h)), ( 2 d - 3 h)/(d - 2 h), 1 + d/( 2 (d - 2 
h)), (2 (d^2 - 2 d h + h^2))/(d - 2 h)^2};
h=1;
qc = Abs[q[[1;;6]]];
qb = -Abs[q[[7;;9]]];
qstar=Join[qc,qb];
Manipulate[ListPlot[qstar]‌​,{d,0.01,1}]
```

It doesn't work...ListPlot doesn't plot...

Comment: Hard to judge without the code which does not work but I guess this is the answer: [how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate). Is that the casE?

Comment: It is not nice to change the question once answers are given. Now they look off topic and you haven't even given any notice. p.s. see `Join`.

Comment: I was wondering what question @Aardvark2012 was answering. :)

Comment: you are missing a `{` on `q` to begin with. Near as I can tell that is the entire problem, voting to close as due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimension of `q` is always 9 with the first six positive and last three negative, then you can just write:

```
qstar = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1} Abs[q]
```

Otherwise, you can use some trickery to get the multiplying vector.