# Manipulate with a vector function

Tags: manipulate

Is there someone who can explain why this manipulate does not work

```
v = {a, b, c}; s = sn;
amapp[v_, s_] := Module[{vv = v, ss = s}, d = Total[vv]/ss;
   q = N[vv/d];
  qq = \[LeftFloor]q\[RightFloor];
  res = q - qq;(*reste*)
  raa = ss - Total[qq];(*reste à attribuer*)
  raa1 = Table[1, {i, Length[vv]}];
  res1 = Table[
    If[MemberQ[Ordering[res, raa, #1 > #2 &], i], qq[[i]] + raa1[[i]],
      qq[[i]]], {i, Length[qq]}]]
Manipulate[
 amapp[v, s], {a, 1, 1000}, {b, 1, 1000}, {c, 1, 1000}, {sn, 1, 1000}]
```

Comment: closely related: [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478), does this anwer your question?

Comment: Kuba This is perfect. But what must I do if I want the length of v to be variable {a, b, c, ....}

Comment: [Can a function be made to accept a variable amount of inputs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/5478)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem with:

```
Manipulate[{v, s}, {a, 1, 1000}, {b, 1,1000}, {c, 1, 1000}, {sn, 1, 1000}]
```

`a,b,c` remain unevaluated with your `v` and `s` defined outside your `Manipulate`. Why? **Because** the `a,b,c` in your Manipulate are locally scoped.   Can see e.g. w/
`Manipulate[{Hold[FullForm[a]], FullForm[v]}, {a, 1, 1000}]`.  Sometimes using `Hold[FullForm[.]]` can help you figure out the actual variable names at play are.

Can resolve e.g. (as Kuba comments) with:

```
Manipulate[amapp[{a, b, c}, sn], {a, 1, 1000}, {b, 1, 1000}, {c, 1, 1000}, {sn, 1, 1000}]
```

Or if you insist on defining a `v` and `s`, do so within the `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[v = {a, b, c}; s = sn; 
 amapp[v, s], {a, 1, 1000}, {b, 1, 1000}, {c, 1, 1000}, {sn, 1, 1000}]
```

Comment: Sometimes I feel so stupid. Thanks, Both of you. But I must underline that what, at the end, I want is to have the length of v variable. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  You want to manipulate the length and content of $v$?  i.e. have a slider for size of your vector $v$ and a separate slider for each of those $v_1, \ldots , v_n$?