# Using Manipulate command for some plots in one graph

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I have list functions which have two variables. I want to plot the list in terms of one variable and show effects of the other variable on the plots using `Manipulate` or `Animate` command of Mathematica. After I did it, nothing was plotted and I could not figure it out this problem. It's kind of you if you help me. In the following the code has been brought.

```
thelist = Table[n = 0;
L = 2;
τ = 2;
ε = (1/2)((N[BesselJZero[
     Sqrt[(χ - 3/2)^2 + (χ*L*(L + 1))/3 + τ*(τ + 3)*(1 - χ)
], n + 1]])^2 - α m), {m, -2, 2, 1}];

Manipulate[ 
  Plot[thelist, {α, 0, 1}
  , PlotLegends -> {"m=-2", "m=-1", "m=0", "m=1", "m=2"}
  , PlotStyle -> {Green, Black, Yellow, Blue, Red}
  ]
, {χ, 0, 1}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a work around. Something strange is happening. But this makes it work. It might be the strange variable name you used [Chi] ? I do not know why. But adding new control variable `z` and then using this made it work.

[image]

```
thelist = Table[n = 0;
   L = 2;
   \[Tau] = 2;
   \[CurlyEpsilon] = (1/
       2) ((N[BesselJZero[
           Sqrt[(\[Chi] - 3/2)^2 + (\[Chi]*L*(L + 1))/
              3 + \[Tau]*(\[Tau] + 3)*(1 - \[Chi])], 
           n + 1]])^2 - \[Alpha] m), {m, -2, 2, 1}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[thelist /. \[Chi] -> z], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"m=-2", "m=-1", "m=0", "m=1", "m=2"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Black, Yellow, Blue, Red}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 23}],
 {z, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, dear Nasser. Your suggestion was simple and it worked out.

Comment: Isn't it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478 or any of linked closely related ones?

Comment: @Kuba I have not see the question you linked to before. If you think it is duplicate question, please feel free to close this as duplicate.

Comment: @Nasser it is very close but I believe there is a better one somewhere. I don't have time to search so I will leave it with peace :)