# Modifying a global variable within a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to change a variable using `Manipulate`, like this:

```
var = something;
var = 
  Manipulate[f[var, {a, b, c}],
    {{a, .8}, -1, 1},
    {{b, 0}, -1, 1},
    {{c, 0}, -1, 1}];
```

> var

I read the `Manipulate` and the `Dynamic` tutorial in the Wolfram documentation, but I still can't figure it out.

Does anyone got any clue? Other than, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate) ?

Comment: It appears that a function $f$ is used but not defined in the example.

Comment: yeah, though it's just an example

Comment: `Manipulate[var = f[var,{a,b,c}],{{a,.8},-1,1},{{b,0},-1,1},{{c,0},-1,1}];` is that what you want?

Comment: @Kuba. Don't you think what you suggest might lead to run-away recursion?

Comment: @m_goldberg you are right. Probably can be fixed with TrackedSymbols. I was trying to confirm I get the question right.

Comment: @EmilianoTonizzo an example that is not clear. Is `f` supposed to modify `var` or only use it to return a value you will later use to assign to `var`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
var = 42;

SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[v_Symbol, {a_, b_, c_}] := (v = (a + b)/(2 + c))

Manipulate[f[var, {a, b, c}],
  {{a, .8}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{b, 0}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{c, 0}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Dynamic @ var
```

> ```
> 0.49
> ```

The dynamic evaluation of `var` is made to show that the global value `var` is updated as the sliders move.

Comment: @Kuba. Good edit. I should have remembered, that since `Set` is also `HoldFirst`, I didn't need the `Unevaluated`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, didn't know about SetAttributes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a*x^2 + b*Sqrt[x] - x, {x, 0, 10}],
 {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}
 ]
```

Where you may call `var=a*x^2 + b*Sqrt[x] - x` in your post. You should be able to get the plot of this function `var`.

your post has other problems such as `var` is something and `something` is assigned to `Manipulate`. Many thing are mixed up in your question.