# Manipulate Sine plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot Sin[a*x] and have used the following code:

```
Plot[Sin[a*x], {a,0,10},{x, 0, 10}]
```

But I am not getting any plot. Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you expect to get? Have you seen `Plot` documentation?

Comment: `DensityPlot[Sin[a*x], {a, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]`

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 10}]
```

or this?

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[a*x], {a, 0, 2}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Yes, something like the first one. Thanks

Comment: I tried `f[max_] := Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, max}]` `Manipulate[f[max], {a, 1, 5}, {max, 10, 20}]`. But, that wasn't giving me the desired result either. Didn't understand why though

Comment: @Maria because https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot3D[Sin[a*x], {a,0,10},{x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Can't I get a 2D plot?

Comment: There are three dimensions here: $a$, $x$, and $\sin(a x)$. Project one out and you can have a 2D plot; but you'll have to say how.