# Manipulate and ListLinePlot

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I have the following code:

```
Mat = DiagonalMatrix @ {α, β, χ}; 
vec = Diagonal @ Mat; 
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[vec], 
  {α, 1, 20}, {β, 1, 20}, {χ, 1, 20}
]
```

but it doesn't work?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can move `Mat` and `vec` inside or convert them to functions to pass parameter values later. Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate

Comment: My original code is more complicated, I can't simply move "{α, β, χ}" in the plot because I have to use "vec"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to move the functions inside, then the alternative is to use substitution.

```
ClearAll[a0, b0, c0];
Mat = DiagonalMatrix[{a0, b0, c0}];
vec = Diagonal[Mat];

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[vec /. {a0 -> a, b0 -> b, c0 -> c}],
 {a, 1, 20},
 {b, 1, 20},
 {c, 1, 20},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c}
 ]
```

This was discussed as Kuba mentioned in the linked to question.  It is also a good idea to add `TrackedSymbols` option all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat = DiagonalMatrix @ {α, β, χ};
vec = Diagonal @ Mat;
```

**Initialization + Function + Evaluate**

You can define a function `v` using the option `Initialization` and use it in the first argument of `ListLinePlot`:

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[v[α, β, χ]], {α, 1,  20}, {β, 1, 20}, {χ, 1, 20}, 
 Initialization -> {v = Function[{α, β, χ}, Evaluate[vec]]}]
```

[image]

**With + Evaluate**

You can replace `vec` with `With[{α = α, β = β, χ = χ}, Evaluate @ vec]` in the the first argument of `ListLinePlot` (as an alternative way to force injection of parameter values into `vec`):

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[With[{α = α, β = β, χ = χ}, Evaluate @ vec]], 
   {α, 1, 20}, {β, 1, 20}, {χ, 1, 20}]
```

> same picture