# globals and `Manipulate`

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

The question is related to a number of questions that have been asked, but no answer is quite what I want, so I will try again. Suppose that I have a model with a lot of state - to give a stupid example, something  like:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
...
z= 26;

foo[bar_]:= bar^(a+b+...+z)
```

Now I want a `Manipulate` expression where I can modify all of my state (and the value of `foo`). To make things more interesting, suppose I have several functions (`foo`, 'baz', `frobboz`) which all need to do this, and I do not want to replicate the code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please always try to bring a minimal example, here a Manipulate is missing. It may be obvious but it is not uncommon that simple questions are misinterpreted.

Comment: Is this topic the answer: [10604](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478), or do you just want to use `LocalizeVariables -> False` option?

Comment: I had tried the localize variables thing before asking, it does not seem to work. that is, setting `bar = 1.0, foo[x_]:= Sin[bar x], Manipulate[Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{bar, 2.0, "bar"}}, LocalizeVariables-> False]` does not work, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: That is why mentioned example was needed from the start. Without a reference to `bar` in the body of Manipulate, it won't update so you need: `Manipulate[bar; Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, Pi}], ....`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, that does work! But it does not address the second part of the question: Should every `Manipulate` have the same fifty variables mentioned by name? Or is there some more elegant way to do encapsulate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do want to keep variables localized then [How are parameters evaluated for a Plot in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478) is the answer.

If you don't then you can use `LocalizeVariables -> False`.

One needs to remember that in case of:

```
bar = 1.0; 
foo[x_]:= Sin[bar x];
Manipulate[Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{bar, 2.0, "bar"}}, LocalizeVariables-> False]
```

there is no sign of `bar` within `Manipulate` body so it won't know it needs to update. A common trick is to put it there e.g.:

```
Manipulate[bar; Plot[...
```

But in case of fity variables and many manipulates it is not neat so you can use `TrackedSymbols -> All` option:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, Pi}], {{bar, 2.0, "bar"}, 1, 10}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False, TrackedSymbols :> All]

Manipulate[
 Plot[-foo[x], {x, 0, Pi}], LocalizeVariables -> False, 
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To explore complex expressions interactively in a notebook, `Dynamic[]` is often more nice than `Manipulate`.

Here is a example where :

- I begin to plot a expression without knowing a priori what parameter I will change
- Then I play with the parameter `bar` first by assigning the value 2, then I create a slider to play dynamically with `bar`
- then I find a nice value for `bar`, so I type `bar = bar` and evaluate the second `bar`in place. That's simply a method to memorize the value somewhere in the notebook, eventually with comments in (*  *)
- then I can play between the different memorized value of `bar` simply by evaluating the corresponding cell
- One can redefine `foo` too and see immediatly the effect.

[image]

Comment: That's very cool!