# Compact notations for multiple variables

Tags: manipulate, variable-definitions

Why does this work

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[{a[1],a[2],a[3]}], {a[1], 0, 1}, {a[2], 0, 1}, {a[3], 0, 1}]
```

But this doesn't?

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Array[a, 3]], {a[1], 0, 1}, {a[2], 0, 1}, {a[3], 0, 1}]
```

How do I rewrite this for $3 \rightarrow 100$ without typing it out?

Comment: related? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate

Comment: The reason is that Manipulate its variables. Therefore, the a[i]'s from Array are not the same variables as the a[i]'s from Manipulate. You may see this by replacing the first by the second e.g. by:Manipulate[vars = Array[a, 3]; 
 ListPlot[Array[a, 3] /. Array[a, 3] -> {a[1], a[2], a[3]}], {a[1], 0,
   1}, {a[2], 0, 1}, {a[3], 0, 1}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to inject objects into the [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate), e.g.:

```
With[
    {arr = Array[a,3], control = Sequence@@Thread[{Array[a,3],0,1}]},
    Manipulate[ListPlot[arr],control]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why do we need the `With` statement here though?